# Change DIV text with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code changes a div's `background-color` when another `div` is dragged on it. How can I modify it it to change divs's text instead of background colour (for example I drop a div with a `<p>Test</p>` inside it and I want to the div which was dragged onto to change its text to `<p>Test</p>`

code:

```
$(".snap").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var drag = ui.draggable;
        var drop = $(this);
        $(this).html(drag.html());
        $(this).attr('name', drag.attr('id'));
        debugger;
    }
});
```

Please check my JSFiddle code which is not working:

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/yrvUq/1/)

Comment: I know its not in the spirit of SO but sometimes I just want to scream : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM

Comment: Aside: Since you cached $(this) as drop, you should replace both instances of $(this) with drop.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$(this).html(drag.html());
```

In place of:

```
$(this).css("background-color", drag.css("background-color"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please check my updated included JSFiddle link

Answer (score 2):

Replace

`$(this).css("background-color", drag.css("background-color"));`

with

`drop.html(drag.html());`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please check my updated included JSFiddle link. tks